# How can I lock race conditon in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, race-condition

I have a Stored Procedure in SQL Server with the following scenario:

In my stored procedure I have a function for getting the max serial. I get the max serial and insert it in a table:

```
Set @Serial = GetMaxSerial(...)
Insert Into MyTable (Serial,...) Values (@Serial,...)
```

Sometimes my stored procedure is executed 2 times concurrently in a way that both, get same max serial for example 100 and try to insert it in MyTable. The first insert is done successfully but the last fails and I get error about key.

How can I lock these two lines of codes and force my sp to run these lines of code together?

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Use a sequence or an identity column? Failing that, use a transaction with the `UPDLOCK` table hint or running at the serializable transaction isolation level. Failing that, use an application lock (`sp_getapplock`)

Comment: +1 ta.speot.is. @breceivemail: The first thing, and the most simple simple you could do is to create an UNIQUE index on Serial column. *This will prevent duplicate values*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good scenario for SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level. Transaction isolation level decides what level to access other transactions has to a Row/Resource when one is already working with the Row/Resource. To read more about  transaction isolation levels Read this link [`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259216%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

BEGIN TRANSACTION 

  Set @Serial = GetMaxSerial(...)
  Insert Into MyTable (Serial,...) Values (@Serial,...)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```